# C++ Child class inheriting from parent class that has std::vector objects

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, stdvector

I'm doing some game creation for fun and to gain a better understanding of C++. I'm having a bit of issue with my first inheritance class. As in most games, the main parent class is a sprite, however, instead of giving each an image and a rect, I'm giving an animation and a body (which will be multiple shapes but for now, it's just a rect. The issue is that no matter how I try to restructure any of the copy constructors, I continue to get this compiler error:

```
Error C2036 'Animation *const ': unknown size (compiling source file Box.cpp)
```

It leads to this error page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2036?

My understanding is that there is an error somewhere in the chain below that I'm just too new to recognize. The other piece of important info is that I'm using `std::vector`. Whenever I click on the error it takes me to the vector file. Any variables that end with 's' are `std::vector`, but I'll put in the variable types for all the variables being passed in the copy constructors so it's clear.

If everything below is fine, I included my Github repo if you want to look into it your self: https://github.com/CalebADB/Static-Motion/tree/Box-UI

Divergently tell me in the comments what else I should include.

Box.cpp

```
Box::Box(const Sprite & source_sprite)
    :
    Sprite(source_sprite) //Sprite
{}
```

Sprite.cpp

```
Sprite::Sprite(const Sprite & source_sprite)
    :
    animations(source_sprite.animations), //std::vector<Animation>
    body(source_sprite.body) //Rect
{}
```

Animation.cpp

```
Animation::Animation(const Animation & source_animation)
    :
    spriteSheet(source_animation.spriteSheet), //Surface
    frameRects(source_animation.frameRects), //std::vector<Rect>
    frameNum(source_animation.frameNum), //int
    chroma(source_animation.chroma), //Color
    holdTime(source_animation.holdTime) //float
{}
```

Rect.cpp

```
Rect::Rect(const Rect& source_rect) // copy ctr
    :
    orig_position(source_rect.position),
    orig_dimension(source_rect.dimension),
    position(source_rect.position),
    dimension(source_rect.dimension)
{
}
```

Comment: A compiler message usually refers to a certain line number in your code. We don't get to see the full message, nor any indication of what actual line the message refers to, so our ability to help you is very limited. Also, please read about creating a [mcve]. A link to a git repo isn't it.

Comment: If the error is in Box.cpp, then please provide us with content of that file. See [mcve] for help.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You declare your vector like this:

```
std::vector<class Animation> animations;
```

This will forward declare the *class* `Animation`, which cannot work, because `std::vector` needs to know the actual class, as it uses an internal array that needs to have the correct size to fit `Animation` instances. Also `std::vector` needs access to the default constructor.

**Solution**

To fix this you have to include `Animation.h` and declare your vector like this:

```
std::vector<Animation> animations;
```

**Further notes**

You should update your question to include the relevant piece of code, which is `Sprite.h`. Your compiler tells you this.

You probably want to make `getAnimations()` return a reference, otherwise it will copy the entire vector everytime it's called.